# AngularJS is not seeing my js in the Scripts folder

Tags: angularjs, scripting, directory

Good morning people.
I'm studying AngularJS and found a situation that I can not solve.
I use Visual Studio 2013 and am creating an empty project, and including the step-by-step codes.

When you rotate the application, the angle is not working properly.

[Fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4d5D.png)

[Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rc6H.png)

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This error in the figure occurs because `success` was deprecated since angular version 1.4. instead of success use `then` to catch the response

```
$http.get('url')
.then(function(response){
   console.log(response.data) // result 
})
```